# Why does searching for more wildcard tags result in fewer search results?

Tags: support, tag-search

A search for `[amazon-*] hasaccepted:false` results in 32,000 answers.

However, a search for `[amazon-*] [aws-*] hasaccepted:false` results in only 11,000 answers, even though the displays shows both terms result in `OR` statements:

[image: Search conditions]

Why would searching for more OR conditions result in fewer results?

Comment: Are you sure you've got all `[amazon-*]` tags in that search?

Comment: It appears that **a wildcard tag search is limited to 20 tags**, so there could actually be questions that I'm missing because they have other tags. Is there a way to include more than 20 tags tags in a wildcard search of one term?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ah! A search for either `[amazon-*]` or `[aws-*]` each result in 20 tags.

I've just noticed that the list of tags (shown above) **does not have an OR** between the `amazon` and `aws` tags, so it must be doing an **AND**.

Indeed, I've just found that searching for `[amazon-*] OR [aws-*]` results in 57,000 tag results. So, the answer is that it needed an **OR**. I didn't notice this earlier.