# Searching: exclude all but one tag.

Tags: support, tags, search, wildcard

Whilst reading this question: [We need to improve our [communication]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356641/we-need-to-improve-our-communication?noredirect=1#comment515298_356641) I wanted to get some number regarding the amount of questions using [communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/communication) as their only tag. I decided to do a search using: [is:question and [communication] and -[*]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:question+%5Bcommunication%5D+and+-%5B%2A%5D) This showed less results then doing just a search for [communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/communication). So I thought I had achieved my goal.

As I found out later this wasn't exactly true. When you scroll down far enough in the search results you'll find questions with multiple tags. So I investigated what questions were excluded using `and -[*]`. It turned out that instead of using the `and` to join both tags it was used as search parameter in the questions.

I read that using wildcards (*) in tags is something that should work for example from this question: [Why does searching for more wildcard tags result in fewer search results?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339830/why-does-searching-for-more-wildcard-tags-result-in-fewer-search-results). Also tag exclusion is something that should work according to [the help on searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

So what exactly breaks this query? Is it the wildcard being the sole character of the tag, which makes it search for tags with length 1, instead of all possible lengths?